# How to take a snapshot in vlc QT?

Tags: qt5, vlc, libvlc, vlc-qt

Hello I have built VLC Qt Library in QT 5.5.1 on Ubuntu. 
Now I want to add snapshot feature in it. Is there anyway or any idea?
Please mention. If you have even little bit of idea.

Comment: [There is](https://wiki.videolan.org/Take_a_snapshot/) already a way of taking snapshots in VLC, isn't there?

Answer (score 0):

you should use the VlcVideo class in this library.
at first create a new object from this class. then use this function:

```c++
bool VlcVideo::takeSnapshot (   const QString &     path    )   const
```

you can find more details about the VlcVideo class from this link:
https://vlc-qt.tano.si/reference/1.1/classVlcVideo.html#a4f3a741285dd9030f76bb996eaa011d4

a very simple code can be like this:

```c++
#include "MayClass.h"
#include "VLCQtCore/Video.h"
void MayClass::initMembers()
{
    _instance = new VlcInstance(VlcCommon::args(), this);
    _player = new VlcMediaPlayer(_instance);
    _video = new VlcVideo(_player);
}
void MayClass::takeSnapShot(QString filename)
{
    _video->takeSnapshot(filename);
}
```